# How do I import a sql data file (the content of file are INSERT queries) into SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, import

I have a `.sql` file with a content of `insert` queries for all tables of my database.

This file is 12 GB in size. I tried to open it with Notepad++, SQL Server Management Studio, and also with chrome browser, but the file is very long. I cant' open it.

How can I import it into my database directly without opening the file and execute the queries?

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: What is a "GO"? (I *thought* it might be a typographical error of GB, but "O" is no where near "B" on any keyboard layouts I can think of.)

Comment: Also, why do you have all your data in a text file? There are back up files in SQL Server for a reason and all supported paid versions of SQL Server support compression, so the file size would likely be significantly less than 12 "GO" (what ever a GO is).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) , the documentation has a full explanation of how to use it but here is a quick sample how to use it, you need to install sqlcmd utility first then open up your cmd command prompt and type the command like this :

```
sqlcmd -S DBSERVER\TESTINSTANCE -d DATABASENAME -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -i "D:/InsertData.sql"
```